# Any idea, how to avoid if statements here

Tags: grails, groovy, refactoring, grails-orm, criteria

Here is the code,

```
    User.createCriteria().list(offset: filter.offset, max: filter.max) {
        if (filter.first-name) eq('firstName', filter.first-name)
        if (filter.last-name) eq('lastName', filter.last-name)
        if (filter.email) eq('email', filter.email)
        if (filter.status) eq('status', filter.status)
        if (...) ...
        .
        .
        order(filter.sort, 'desc')
        order('name')
    }
```

Is there any way to avoid `if`s here?

Comment: You can use groovy ternary operartor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a map?

```
User.createCriteria().list(offset: filter.offset, max: filter.max) {
    [
        'firstName' : filter.first-name,
        'lastName'  : filter.last-name,
        'email'     : filter.email,
        'status'    : filter.status
    ].findAll { it.value }.each { eq it.key, it.value }

    order(filter.sort, 'desc')
    order('name')
}
```

It could be even more dynamic, simply listing the property names.

---

**Update:** what about using closures as keys?

```
User.createCriteria().list(offset: filter.offset, max: filter.max) {
    [
        { eq 'firstName', it } : filter.first-name,
        { eq 'lastName', it }  : filter.last-name,
        { eq 'email', it }     : filter.email,
        { eq 'status', it }    : filter.status,
        { lt 'dob', it }       : filter.dob
    ].findAll { it.value }.each { it.key(it.value) }

    order(filter.sort, 'desc')
    order('name')
}
```

I believe the `it` param can be abstracted using something like [`curry`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#curry(java.lang.Object...))

Comment: Actually, in my case, keys and property names are different. That can be made same, though. Another problem is that, it's not just `eq` what I need; there are a few, like, `ilike`, `ne`, some association's property, etc.. But it's a good idea, anyway. +1

Comment: I think the key/value should be reversed, then it would be more straightforward to read... A good point is that the `if` (`findAll`) is only expressed in a single place, and applied against a collection.

Answer (score 1):

And to make it even less readable but less repetitive you could include a map of your searchable items and try something like this :

```
filter.searchList=[first-name:'firstName',last-name:'lastName',
email:'email', status:'status']
User.createCriteria().list(offset: filter.offset, max: filter.max) {
     filter.searchList?.each { k,v ->
      !(filter."${k}" ?: eq(v, filter."${k}")
     }
    .
    .
    order(filter.sort, 'desc')
    order('name')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.